# Installing Chromium on Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, chromium, apt

I'm currently trying to install Chromium in Debian Wheezy. When I try `sudo apt-get install chromium`, I get the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
chromium : Depends: libspeechd2 but it is not installable
           Depends: libxssl but it is not installable
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, apart from building from source, but that doesn't seem to work so well either. What can I do?

Comment: Did you run `apt-get update` before trying to install? What sources are you using (post your `/etc/apt/sources.list`)? Which Debian version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try apt-get -f install and then run apt-get install chromium again

Comment: Doesn't work for me